# run a constant query against mysql using php without refreshing HTML page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Im looking at outputting mysql query results into a table on a php page where the 1st column of the table is the result and the 2nd column is populated with a Javascript timer

however my goal is to have it so that when data comes into the mysql database it display on the table and then when it stops being picked up by the query remove it from the table

the issue i face however is im not sure how to do this without resetting the javascript timer everytime the query is run,

I have gone through a couple of questions that have mentioned to use ajax and this would be fine but im not sure what i would put the HTML side

EDIT:
the below is now my second attempt code using ajax but i cant get the table to display it errors as unexpected token < line 27

my current page load Code to call the data is as followed:

PHP

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
#   header('Content-Type: applicaton/json');

$sql = "SELECT 
* 
FROM
(SELECT
  beacon,location,
  COUNT(location) AS counter 
FROM `track`
WHERE `date` = CURDATE() and `time` > NOW() - interval 60 second
GROUP BY beacon) AS SubQueryTable
ORDER BY beacon + 0 ASC;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


$result = mysqli_query($conn ,  $sql);
   $rows = array();
   while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
    }

   echo json_encode($rows);
    $conn->close();
?>
```

HTML

```
    $.get('vendor/fetch.php', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var row;
        response.forEach(function(item, index) {
            console.log(item);

(unexpexted token here) 
<table id="table">
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    ?>
    <tr style="background-color: <?php echo $row['item.location'];?>">
    <td><?php echo $row['item.beacon'];?></td>
    <td> <span class='minutes'>00</span>:<span class='seconds'>00</span> 
    </td>
    </tr>

    <?php } 

    mysqli_close($con);  
    ?>
    </table>
        });
    });


        function updateTable() {
        //console.log('function called');
        $.get('vendor/fetch.php', function(response) {
            response.forEach(function(item, index) {
                console.log(item.beacon);

            });
        });

    var updateTableInterval = setInterval(updateTable, 100);
    };
</script>

 </head>

 <body>
<script>
var sec = 0;

function pad(val) {
return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
}
var timer = setInterval(function () {
$(".seconds").html(pad(++sec % 60));
$(".minutes").html(pad(parseInt(sec / 60, 10)));
}, 1000);
</script> 
</body>
```

Comment: You should do it in 2 files, your JS is being returned everytime you run the file, so you actually probably have several timers running.

Comment: if i was to do it using ajax and have a php file to call the results and a html file to call the ajax would i end up with the same issue?

Comment: Ultimately, you may have to trigger the ajax the first time (manually), so you don't have to wait for the initial timer.  So you will want to make a function of the code in the interval callback, then call that once manually, the rest from the interval.  Unless you don't mind waiting the second for the first call to happen.

Comment: I don't know that it will solve "All" you problems but it's probably not correct either ... :)

Comment: okay thank you ill look at that then

Comment: yea, every-time you run that you get the full output including the JS, then if you replace the old JS with this, you reset everything.  So you have to just work with the table if that make sense.  You may also get an error in JS because of this `function pad` defining the same function multiple times etc.

Comment: your script is outputting both JSON and HTML at the same time. Therefore trying to parse your response as JSON and turn it into a JS variable is failing. Ensure the script only outputs JSON when that's the data you need. You could either put the code which generates JSON into a separate file, or find a way for the PHP to know which format is required - e.g. via a querystring variable or something - and use an `if` statment to decide which output to create, and then make it die(); after it's finished that type. Whatever you choose, you can't continue to output in both formats at once.

Comment: @ADyson sorry to trouble you but which bit would you remove, my knowledge of code is basic and the above is patched together from other pages i have that have a similar outcome but work differently

Comment: the bit which echoes JSON (and the code block which surrounds it). If you move that to a separate script, and add back in the code to run the SQL query to get the data, then that script will do nothing except create the JSON and echo it. Then you can change your AJAX request to call that new script file instead of this one, and it won't get the results muddled up.